# Location geofencing in a single street

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

I want to know if is possibile with the Google Play Services Location API have a proximity alert in a range of long/lat that it isn't a circle with a radius??

an example could be a street.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK its taking center & radius, thus the area to monitor is indeed circle. anyway, you could always make a simple logic yourself with normal location APIs which with you could indeed monitor areas which are not circles.

Comment: I have read normal location API cause battery drain. Do you know some custom library battery friendly?

Comment: I think the geofencing API is done already as well as it can be done.